# Does gcc guarantee an aligned access to volatile integer to be atomic?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Does gcc (for C and C++) guarantee an aligned access to volatile object to be atomic?

```
*((volatile unsigned int*)ADDRESS_DIVISIBLE_BY_4) = SOME_CONSTANT;
```

If unsigned int size is 4, is it guaranteed that the store machine instruction behind the line above will not be teared?

Note: The question only covers atomicity, not ordering. **It is not related to concurrency but to memory-mapped registers** which may require one-step store instruction.

Comment: http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/

Comment: I've already answerd from the general point of view.  But can you be more specific on your hardware architecture and why you want it to be atomic ?

Comment: I refer to cases where you need to write to the whole 32-bit register in one-step. It is common in microcontroller programming. The question is how to ensure it's done properly from C language level.

Comment: No. GCC's AVR backend doesn't atomically write (16-bit) `int` for instance, since the architecture only provides 8-bit memory accesses. Generally speaking you'll need to settle for `sig_atomic_t` to insure volatile atomicity.

Answer (score 2):

No volatile can never be assumed to be atomic.  It's [almost useless from the point of view of concurrency](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming).

Comment: So if you want to write to 32-bit hardware register in one step, how can you achieve this? And one more question - what about WRITE_ONCE and READ_ONCE macros in Linux kernel?

Comment: @mrn why do you want it in one step? Why not use GCC atomic extensions?

Comment: @user3528438 I want it in one step simply because my hardware requires a 32-bit access to a memory-mapped I/O. GCC atomic extensions would be useful, but for example Linux kernel defines WRITE_ONCE/READ_ONCE macros only based on alignment and volatile qualifier. Therefore I am asking about the guarantees given by GCC.

Comment: Your code may generate "atomic instructions on modern hardware" (see link to the intel article) like x86.  But GCC is targeting a much larger number of processor [architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection#Architectures).  As the C++ standard doesn't give any atomicity guarantees for alligned volatiles, you will certainly not get some for GCC.

Comment: On the other side "memory mapped I/O" is exactly what volatile is meant for, independently of the atomicity question.

Comment: @mrn If you look at linux kernel code `__raw_writel` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__raw_writel), out of 14 ISAs, 6 use assembly, 2 use volatile store, 4 use `__force`ed volatile store, 2 written for alpha ISA are written with great care which I can not fully understand. So I guess currently the best thing to do is to use `__raw_writel`, if one for your target exists.

Comment: @user3528438 And what is the puropse of __raw_writel? What is it used for?

Comment: @mrn If you look at the "referenced" in the LXR page it seems it's used by all memory mapped IO drivers.